# How to read pieces of a string

Tags: java, string, context-free-grammar

Im trying to read strings such as combinations of Capital and lower case letters such as aSb for context free languages but I don't know how to read each piece of the string separately like read first a then S then b with various amounts of letters so not just 3 it can be any combination of letters.

Comment: Can you give another example to understand what you exactly mean by combination of U/L letters. Ex: how would ABcdEF works ?

Comment: Could you improve your question? How would you separate the pieces of your string? Do you want pieces of lower case and Upper case? For example, the string aaabBBBvvvvv would give 3 pieces, or do you want to be able to read it one letter at a time: a,a,a,b,B,...?

Comment: It seems the OP wants to break the read at every char case differs.

Comment: @Ravinder, The question is not clear enough to tell, so I'm giving him the ability to read at a fine grain and decide what he wants to do with it. :P

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read strings one letter at a time, you can use `charAt()` to convert to a `char` array.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
      char c = myString.charAt(i);
      // Do whatever you need with c
      // If you want to convert it back to a String type, you can do 
      // String s = "" + c;
 }
```

Using the character array:

```
 char[] myCharArray = myString.toCharArray();
 for (int i = 0; i < myCharArray.length; i++) {
      char c = myCharArray[i];
 }
```

Of course if you really just want the String type for some reason, you can use `substring()`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
    String s = myString.substring(i, i+1); 
}
```